# How can we find item based in incomplete name?

Tags: java, commercetools, sphere.io

I have a question about "How can we find product or something else by partial information (name for example)"?. For example in SQL we can use `LIKE`. What can we use in Commercetools to do the same? How can we find category by incomplete name in Java code?

Comment: What does the API documentation say?

Comment: I read the Search and Query documentation there’s nothing like it only a full text match. Also I saw a post that was published in February and at that time there were no functions for this type of task. Therefore, I asked how this can be implemented?

Comment: Well, you should ask the vendor: https://commercetools.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question. The product projections api provides search and suggest functionality. It is limited to product data. All other end points support filter by exact match.

see docs https://docs.commercetools.com/http-api-projects-products-search.html#search-productprojections